# Do the big donors to a losing US presidential candidate ever get their money back?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, campaign-finance

Do the big donors to a losing US presidential candidate ever get their money back?  And if so, how, and in how much time?

Comment: I don't think they get their money back (it is a gamble on the winner).

Comment: @hownowbrowncow Yeah, bro, I can imagine that, but still.... I am trying to educate myself about USA, as I am an European. :d

Comment: There's often been a case made that some larger corporations are effectively funding both sides. I've never been entirely sure how accurate or reputable those kinds of figures are though.

Comment: They don't necessarily get their money back if they win, either. Donor = Donation != investment.

Comment: Yeah, good point @origimbo. True, blip, but maybe they'll negotiate ahead some political positions or something like that.

Comment: There are second order considerations too: Big donors do not donate only to win a single election. They might give to both parties/sides to hedge their bets, they might consistently donate based on a special issue to signal their willingness to back up or fight candidates that do not agree with them, they might gain influence in a party by establishing themselves as a reliable big donors for that party across several election cycles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### There are no refund requirements

The Federal Election Commission oversees national elections. They have compiled the various election laws in a [single document](http://www.fec.gov/law/feca/feca.pdf). I've read some of these laws, searched for things, went through the index, and more - and have found nothing about any situation where refunds are required for campaign donors - whether they win or lose.

### Refunds may be optional

However, candidates may refund money at their own discretion. Back in 2010, [ABC](http://abcnews.go.com/Politics/refunds-campaign-donations-70-percent/story?id=11395466) had a story about the sudden rise in refunds of campaign contributions for various reasons. Generally, these refunds were because candidates had accepted money from organizations who made them look bad (for example, some of the refunds were connected to large banks after the banking collapse).

### Primaries

The same ABC article mentions a law requiring candidates to refund contributions if they drop out before their primary (or caucus). This is because the election laws define elections as being federal elections (general, special, run-off, etc.) and primaries. If you accept campaign contributions and don't actually participate in an election, then you don't have a lawful usage of those funds.

Comment: Alright, I find your comment really informed. When I asked the question, I had in mind that maybe it is possible for the donors to secretly (i.e. behind doors) make deals with the candidates, like, if you don't win, we will be wanting our cash back, or at least a part of it, etc. I am also aware that this depends on the donor's personality, attitude, etc.

Comment: I'd like to see this answer also note that the laws are the same whether you win or lose.

Comment: @PaulEgnahcxekcats No I don't think that's common.  It's more likely that they say "if you win, you approve of some appointment, remove or submit some new legislature, something like that".  For example, large multinational banks supported hillary clinton because she was friendly to this sort of environment and wouldn't rock the boat.  Trump, on the other hand wants more favor to fall towards the common Worker at the expense of multinational corporations and globalized markets distributing wealth across borders.  Therefore, they back the one whom is best for business.

Comment: @PaulEgnahcxekcats - Really, there is no mechanism for this to happen. They could try to make such a deal, but they don't have any way to enforce it. And of course there is no way to refund money that has already been spent. Elected officials are always worried about funds for the next election, so there is always the possibility of withholding future campaign donations.

Comment: I see, hownowbrowcow, thanks a lot... True, @indigochild . Sorry for saying "your comment", instead of "your answer". I'm a newbie here.. :)) I tried to edit my comment, for the moment I am not able to do it. :d :d :d

Comment: @indigochild I would note the difficulty of returning spent money in your answer.

Comment: I've found some clues also here: 
http://mentalfloss.com/article/29636/what-happens-leftover-campaign-funds-when-candidate-drops-out
@notstoreboughtdirt It seems that the superPACs can refund the money to the original donors.

Comment: Is there any history here?  Did HRC actually return any donations in 2008 when she lost the primary battle with Obama?

Comment: @PaulEgnahcxekcats from that article: "The goal, however, is always to spend all of that money." Money paid to Viacom for a commercial is not going back to Boeing as a refunded donation.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt I am aware that this is the goal. Anyway, I was asking about special, exceptional situations. :) But I got my answer from that article. It is possible to refund the original donors, if they wish, but just in the case of the superPACs.